# Add style to child element inside target

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid, addclass

Currently I have a script that adds a `display:block` to the target element by matching the ID.

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
```

...But i now want to change that so that it add's the style or class to a child DIV element.

Comment: for example your variable id is: var id = '#parent'; then change it to id = '#parent > div';

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.css()` to add some style and `.addClass()` to add any class to the target element.
**Reference :**

[CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab your child element by using this javascript code:

```
document.getElementById(id)[0].style.display = 'block';
```

It's just like accessing a certain item inside of an array.

Comment: `document.getElementById(id)[0].style.display = 'block';` does not return a array!! So you cannot use `[0]`. Understand difference between `Element` and `Elements`